# How to deploy UWP to lumia950?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I can't find my lumia 950 in this list.
[image: Where is my lumia950?]

After I switched to Devices then deploy, VS2015 gave me the error message:

1>Error : DEP6400 : Failed to deploy. Make sure another deployment or debugging session is not in progress for the same emulator or device from a different instance of Visual Studio: Error writing file '%FOLDERID_SharedData%\PhoneTools\11.0\Debugger\bin\RemoteDebugger\msvsmon.exe'. Error 0x80070003: The system cannot find the path specified.

THX

Comment: Make sure you have installed the latest Emulator which is 10586.

Comment: @JuniperPhoton I think problem is SDK version too. THX. I'm upgrading my SDK.

Comment: @JuniperPhoton After upgrading sdk, the problem hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Is developer mode enabled on your Lumia? See https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/just-released-windows-10-application-deployment-tool

Comment: @BoltClock Of course.

Answer (score 1):

After I upgrading my phone OS to 10.0.10586.29, the problem has been fixed. THX!